# bycrypt node module not working on my m1 MacBook

Tags: node.js, apple-m1, yarn-workspaces

Ok so I bought this MacBook Air 2020 with the m1 a few days ago and it's been fine until I tried to import my work from GitHub to start working on it on the laptop, installed everything and fixed most issues but now it seems like it doesn't work it gives me this error

```
Error: dlopen(/Users/jaberghanem/Desktop/innentialApp/backend/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/jaberghanem/Desktop/innentialApp/backend/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))
at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1057:18)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jaberghanem/Desktop/innentialApp/backend/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (/Users/jaberghanem/Desktop/innentialApp/backend/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:152:7)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/jaberghanem/Desktop/innentialApp/backend/src/utils/encryption/_encryptor.js:1:1)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
at loader (/Users/jaberghanem/Desktop/innentialApp/backend/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
```

[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: Did you version control your node_modules directory?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my M1 Macbook with node v14.

For me switching to node v16 solved the issue. If you're using nvm, you can write:

```
nvm install 16

nvm use 16
```

Might work with node v18 as well - hope this helps!